# Feedback on USB-C Power + LiPo Battery + Nema 17 Stepper Motor PCB Design

Tags: arduino, usb, battery-charging, lipo, usb-c

TL;DR: I need a technical check on my circuit design that utilizes LiPo battery & USB-C charging.

Hi everyone,

I've been working on a project to build my own camera slider. It's powered by Sparkfun Pro Micro and A4988 Stepper Driver Modules. Right now, I'm using only one stepper motor but I do want to have the option to have two more stepper motors for more degrees of movements in the slider. Each motor is rated at 12V and 0.4A/phase.

I'm designing the PCB (on EasyEDA) and I have a few constraints in terms of how it will be powered; either through a USB-C connector or the LiPo battery. The battery itself can also be recharged by the USB-C port. As for the power through the USB-C port, I'm going with the standard 15W option (5V & 3A) so I don't have to deal with the whole USB-PD circuitry BS that comes with it. There is a switch that will turn on the Arduino & motors from either the battery or USB-C power source. When the switch is off, the battery can still be recharged if the USB-C is plugged in.

For the components, I'm thinking of choosing this [battery from Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/353) as it should provide enough power for now. I also found this [YouTube video from Electronoobs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7AFbrKi0t_4) on battery charging and boost converting so I followed along for my circuit design. I mixed and matched to try to fit my need. I've attached a screenshoot of the circuit that involves the power management. Note that the "C" and "NO" nets are the common and normally-open pins of the power switch. The diode "D2" is to force the anode (+ side) to flow the positive/conventional current from the battery to the boost converter and not back into the TP4056 recharging IC. Diode "D1" is to prevent the 5V current from the USB-C Vbus to flow to the anode of the battery which is 3.7V.

If you see any potential problems with my design or got some questions, please comment on it. I'm still very new to this area of circuitry. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I worry that your boost converter output impedance is too high for a stepper motor with BEMF and resonance. Better to use the right battery voltage with 10A surge capability than boost a single cell with a boost converter with <10% of that capacity  Maybe if you had soft start with 470uF or a 30W boost reg . Many users here report problems this way.

Comment: What kind of problems specifically are you referring to? I initially tried to find a 12V battery that is portable enough for the application. But it seems all lithium batteries are 3.7V nominal. AA batteries are 1.5V so I think I have to boost it no matter what. The battery I choose is 3 lithium cells in parallel so it has a peak current draw of 3.3A and can draw constantly at 1.3A at least.

Comment: Do you know what controls load regulation , overshoot , resonance in voltage regulation with motor loads?

Comment: I unfortunately don't know much if anything at all about overshoot, resonance. I've just ran my first design using a 12V 1.5A DC jack to power the stepper through the A4988 Module.